# My SQL query keeps giving me an error

Tags: mysql, sql

**UPDATE**

I tried just running this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'stickynotes'.'stickynotes' ('id' INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
'note' VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
'created' TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY ('id') ,
UNIQUE INDEX 'id_UNIQUE' ('id' ASC) )
ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

and I get the error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''stickynotes'.'stickynotes' ('id' INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 'note' VARCHAR(' at line 1

When I try to run the sql query below I get the error, #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''stickynotes'.'stickynotes'' at line 1

What is wrong with the query?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `stickynotes`.`stickynotes` ;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stickynotes`.`stickynotes` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`note` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
`created` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC) )
ENGINE = MyISAM;
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Data for table `stickynotes`.`stickynotes`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
START TRANSACTION;
USE `stickynotes`;
INSERT INTO `stickynotes`.`stickynotes` (`id`, `note`, `created`) VALUES (NULL, 'This is a sticky    note you can type and edit.', NULL);
INSERT INTO `stickynotes`.`stickynotes` (`id`, `note`, `created`) VALUES (NULL, 'Let's see if it  will work with my iPhone', NULL);
COMMIT;
```

Comment: why do you use `stickynotes`.`stickynotes` instead of simply `stickynotes`?

Comment: The syntax highlighting has given you a pretty good clue. In your last INSERT statement you haven't escaped the apostrophe in `Let's`. It should be `Let''s`...

Comment: @Lashane The database and the table are both named stickynotes

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

> INSERT INTO `stickynotes`.`stickynotes` (`id`, `note`, `created`)
>   VALUES (NULL, 'Let's see if it  will work with my iPhone', NULL);

Try:

> INSERT INTO `stickynotes`.`stickynotes` (`id`, `note`, `created`)
>   VALUES (NULL, '**Let''s** see if it  will work with my iPhone', NULL);

The error is here : **Let''s** see if it  will work with my iPhone

Comment: Hi Franz just running the first section of the query, that is without the insert section still gives the same error

Comment: Use grave accent ` instead of quote ' to delimit database, table and field names

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you're already defining `USE`stickynotes` so having the schema name within the insert is pointless

Secondly, you haven't escaped the `Let's` it should be `'Let\'s`

```
INSERT INTO `stickynotes`.`stickynotes` (`id`, `note`, `created`) 
VALUES (NULL, 'Let\'s see if it  will work with my iPhone', NULL);
```

Full code block:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `stickynotes`.`stickynotes` ;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stickynotes`.`stickynotes` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`note` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
`created` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC) )
ENGINE = MyISAM;
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Data for table `stickynotes`.`stickynotes`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
START TRANSACTION;
USE `stickynotes`;
INSERT INTO stickynotes (`id`, `note`, `created`) VALUES (NULL, 'This is a sticky    note you can type and edit.', NULL);
INSERT INTO stickynotes (`id`, `note`, `created`) VALUES (NULL, 'Let\'s see if it  will work with my iPhone', NULL);
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Hi Steve, just running the first section of the query, that is without the insert section still gives the same error

Answer (score 0):

Your sencond insert query is failing i.e.

```
INSERT INTO `stickynotes`.`stickynotes` 
(`id`, `note`, `created`) 
VALUES (NULL, 'Let's see if it  will work with my iPhone', NULL);
```

You have a value as `Let's see if it  will work with my iPhone` here `Let's` is having `'` quote and the column value are enclosed in `'` so its treating its illegal i.e its represnted as

insert into the table for the columns `id`, `note`, `created` with values

- NULL
- 'Let'
- s see if it  will work with my iPhone'
- NULL

So here `s see if it  will work with my iPhone'` is throwing the syntax error

You need to escape that using `\` so that mysql knows the quote is a part of the value not the entire column value

```
INSERT INTO `stickynotes`.`stickynotes` 
    (`id`, `note`, `created`) 
    VALUES (NULL, 'Let\'s see if it  will work with my iPhone', NULL);
```

If you use application level to perform the insert operation with prepared statement then this is taken care by that.